# A trouble about the topology of pointwise convergence $({\mathbb{R}}^M,\tau)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(M,d)$ be a separable metric space and $F=\{f_{\lambda}:M\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}:\lambda\in L \}\subset \mathbb{R}^M $ be an equicontinuous family of uniformly bounded functions on $M$.

How can we prove that:

$\boxed{1}\;\; \overline{F}^{\tau}\subset ({\mathbb{R}}^M,\tau)$ is an equicontinuous and uniformly bounded family

$\boxed{2}\;$ $(\overline{F}^{\tau},\tau) \subset ({\mathbb{R}}^M,\tau)$ is metrizable

$L:$ set of indices

$\tau :$ topology of pointwise convergence $({\mathbb{R}}^M,\tau)$

The proof of this fact is analogous to Proposition $3.22$ ?

Any hints would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked for hints, so I'm being "hintish..."

Definition of Uniformly Bounded is that $f_\lambda < N$ for some real number $N$ correct?  If so, all limits of sequences in $F$ are bounded by $N$, since every element in the sequence is bounded by $N$.

A similar argument holds for equicontinuous.

I don't immediately see how to metrize it, although my first gut is to hack out a supremum norm.  That would definitely work for M compact....  Ah, I bet you can metrize it by something like, $d(f_1,f_2) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty |f_1(s_i) - f_2(s_i) | / 2^i$ where the $s_i$ form a separable subset of $M$.

I'm not using the fact that $M$ is a metric space.... so I am probably missing something...